# How to autowire a bean annoted with @service in other class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

In a `SPRING BOOT application` i have a class as below

```
@Service
public class XYZ{
}
```

I want to use above in other class ABC

```
public class ABC{
@Autowired
private XYZ xyx;
}
```

It throws error that XYZ could not be found. I already have @SpringBootApplication in the class where the main method is written. Hence, this will automatically enable @ComponentScan on the package.My understanding is , since XYZ has been annoted with @service, spring scans and creates and registers that bean. How can i access that bean in other class without using xml configuration ?

Comment: When asking about an error, post the actual relevant code, and the complte and exact stack trace of the error. My guess is that the error is related to the disrespect of the conventions described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Answer (score 0):

Well your ABC class also need to have the @Service or @Component annotation. Otherwise, you will get a warning with the following message.

> Autowired memebers must be defined in valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service|...).

```
@Service
public class ABC {

    @Autowired
    private XYZ xyx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class ABC is not in spring boot context, that is reason you can't get a bean. you might get it the following way:

Create an ApplicationContextProvider

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

After you need to call the following way:

```
public class ABC {
   public void method() {
      XYZ xyz = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(XYZ.class);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to configurate @ComponentScan. you need to put the Class XYZ and ABC in the  same level directory with Spring boot application runner class

Answer (score -1):

your class ABC should also be a spring-managed

you can do this by making it a Component

```
@Component
public class ABC{
  @Autowired
  private XYZ xyx;
}
```

or provide it as a Bean

```
 @Configuration
 public SomeConfig{

    @Bean
    public ABC abc(){
        return new ABC();
    }
 }
```

Comment: If Spring scans this class no need of creating a bean.

Comment: @Debopam you provided a valid way to register ABC as a *bean*  ```autowireBean(abc)```  ... so abc is spring-managed

Comment: According to the code ABC is not Spring managed there is not marker annotation.

Comment: @Debopam but it has to be if you want ```@Autowired``` to work

Comment: No There are other ways to work. That's why I gave the example. Even after doing new ABC() Spring can autowire instances with objects. Check my example.

Comment: @Debopam yes please check *your* example! you create a bean! 
while you claimed *no need of creating a bean.*

Comment: Creating a Bean in Spring context is a SIngleton Bean but we can create bean/object using new parameter. Which will not have Autowired bean injected. To inject the dependencies SpringContext to be used.

Comment: the scope of the bean is completely off topic here, but you could use @Scope if needed...  Anyways I rest my case

Answer (score -1):

Use `@ComponentScan("<your root package>")` in you Spring boot application runner class so that it inspects all the components and create the bean which can be autowired. Also Calling class should be a component annotated with @Componenent. If you create object of ABC as new ABC() then

```
ABC abc = new ABC();  
ContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(abc); //Autowiring dependencies

//Then use the abc object which will have instance of XYZ populated.
```

ContextProvider implementation

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * @author dpoddar
 *
 */
@Component("ContextProvider")
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    private static ApplicationContext CONTEXT;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        CONTEXT = applicationContext;
    }
    /**
     * @return the cONTEXT
     */
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return CONTEXT;
    }


    /**
     * Get a Spring bean by type.
     **/
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    /**
     * Get a Spring bean by type.
     **/
    public static <T> T getBean(String beanName,Class<T> beanClass) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName, beanClass);
    }

    /**
     * Get a Spring bean by name.
     **/
    public static Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return CONTEXT.getBean(beanName);
    }

}
```

Comment: you should remove @Autowired on CONTEXT, you cannot autowire __static__ fields in Spring. *(note: CONTEXT will be set via setApplicationContext )*